# ExecutorService threads in waiting second time on Tomcat 7.0.25

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-mvc, tomcat, executorservice

Could somebody help me with this issue.

I have a spring web application deployed on Tomcat 7.0.25 and inside the Controller I have created threads like below

```
   if(condition == true){
    ExecutorService taskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);

    taskExecutor.execute(new SomeRunnable(param1,param2,param3));
    //The above execute is repeated 8 times with different params.

   taskExecutor.shutdown();
   try {
       taskExecutor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE,    TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("exception");
    }
}
```

8 Tasks are created and the first time when the request comes it executes nicely. It finishes properly.

Now , when second time it hits the above code , application freezes, using jvisualvm , I can see that all threads are in waiting.

Could somebody help me point out why on first time it works and second time it stops and tomcat does not respond.

Regards

Comment: Almost certainly not the problem at hand, but it's bad practice to swallow your `InterruptedException` like that. At the very least, call `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` in the catch in order to preserve the fact that the thread was interrupted.

Comment: Second time when request comes it creates the threads , and the application stops and refuses to serve any request as all threads are in waiting status and and the only way out is to start tomcat again. Why all threads are in wait status.

Comment: Can you put more code to make it clear if you are running it in a FOR loop or how??

Comment: taskExecutor.execute(new SomeRunnable(param1,param2,param3)); is repeated 8 times and not in a for loop  with hard coded parameters